# How to cancel vim highlight after I "gd" on a word?

Tags: vim, highlight, words

I use "gd" on a word to highlight all its instance, fine. Then I wish these highlight should disappear because I don't want to be disturbed. Any vim command to dis-highlight last result?

Comment: You can use `:call clearmatches()` to clear highlight. I have this remaped to `<leader>c`

Comment: You are using `gd` for *a side effect*. This is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `clearmatches` or command `noh` to clear all highlights.

```
:noh

:call clearmatches()
```

I've got it re-maped in my `.vimrc`

```
noremap <leader>g :noh<cr>:call clearmatches()<cr>
```

From `:h noh`

> Stop the highlighting for the 'hlsearch' option.  It
>   is automatically turned back on when using a search
>   command, or setting the 'hlsearch' option.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nohlsearch` command, or its short version `nohls`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or `:call clearmatches()`